# MySQL Select data from table1 based on table2

Tags: php, mysql

I want to `SELECT` data `FROM` `status` `table` `WHERE` `account_name or author` is either `$logname` or `$username` and if `account_name or author` are friends from `friends` `table`

### Here is `status table`

**data**    *account_name*  **author**

1 **Hello**         *John* **John**

2 **Am good**   *John*  **Doe**

3 **Please**    *Doe*   **James**

4 **Who is?**   *James*     **Smith**

5 **Hmmm**  *John*  **Williams**

6 **Hell**  *Banks*     **James**

### Here is `friends table`

*user1*     **user2**

*John*  **Doe**

*James*     **Doe**

*Smith*     **James**

*Williams*  **John**

*Banks*     **James**

What I wanted to do is to be able to `SELECT` all data from `status table` where `account_name and author` is John or Doe or John's friends i.e Williams.

So the output of the query when `$username="Doe"` and `$logname="John"` should be 1, 2, 3 and 5, but when `$username="Doe"` and `$logname="Doe"` should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.

Here is what I have tried so far, but am getting all the results from `status` or just the `result` where only `account_name or author` is either `$logname` or `$username`.

```
$username = "Doe";
$logname = "John"; 

$query=mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT s.id, s.account_name, s.author, s.data, s.postdate  FROM status s INNER JOIN  friends f ON f.user1='$username' OR f.user2='$username' WHERE s.account_name='$username' OR s.author='$username' OR s.account_name='$logname' OR s.author='$logname' GROUP BY s.id ORDER BY s.postdate DESC");


    //I have also tried these two queries but not giving me what I want

//$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT * FROM status WHERE account_name = '$username' OR author = '$username' ORDER BY postdate DESC");
    $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    echo " Numbers ".$num_row;
    //$query =mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT s.* , f.* FROM status s, friends f WHERE s.account_name='$user' AND f.user1='$user' OR f.user2='$user'");


    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {


?>
    <tr>
    <td><p><?php echo $row['data']; ?></p></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row['id']; ?></p></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row['author']; ?></p></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row['account_name']; ?></p></td>
    </tr>


<?php   
    }
```

What I have checked so far, please any help will be appreciated.

[Two mysqli queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924127/two-mysqli-queries)

[Difference between left join and right join in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715677/difference-between-left-join-and-right-join-in-sql-server/4715847#4715847)

[How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

[Select results from table1 based on entries on table2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306721/select-results-from-table1-based-on-entries-on-table2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to `SELECT` record of friends of friend when posted on the friend or a friend posted on his friend? Similar to a facebook feed.
I dont know if there is a better way of doing this, but you can try the code bellow, need to improve it or someone can improve it here.

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user1='kira' OR user2 = 'mandekira' OR user2='kira' OR user1 = 'mandekira'");
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
?>
<table>
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $sql = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT * FROM status WHERE (account_name='".$row['user1']."' AND author='".$row['user2']."') OR (account_name='".$row['user2']."' AND author='".$row['user2']."') ORDER BY postdate DESC");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
?>
    <tr>
    <td width="100"><?php echo $row['data']; ?></td>
    <td width="100"><?php echo $row['account_name']; ?></td>
    <td width="100"><?php echo $row['author']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php   
}
    }
?>
</table>
<?php
```

Comment: This is exactly what am looking for. But can I get it in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

That sample data was really helpful, I came up with this:

```
$query=mysqli_query($db_conx, "
 SELECT
`status`.id,
`status`.account_name,
`status`.author,
`status`.`data`
 FROM
`status`
LEFT JOIN friends AS acc_friends ON `status`.account_name IN (acc_friends.friend1, acc_friends.friend2)
LEFT JOIN friends AS au_friends ON `status`.author IN (au_friends.friend1, au_friends.friend2)
WHERE
'$logname' IN (acc_friends.friend1, au_friends.friend1,acc_friends.friend2, au_friends.friend2)
OR '$username' IN (acc_friends.friend1, au_friends.friend1,acc_friends.friend2, au_friends.friend2)
 ");
```

I missunderstood your needs at first, this time is pullign every record which is a friend from author OR account, it then goes thru that result searching for `Banks` or `Doe` (change them to logname and username) in the friends list because searching in account and author again is just redundant.

This query should do the trick :)

Comment: Thank you, let me get to my PC, I will try and let you know.

Comment: I got the same output as the query I posted in the question. But I have added tables structures and more explanation to my question. Thank you.

Comment: I updated the answer with a query that should solve this issue

Comment: Am sorry for late reply, I have been trying to re-manipulate your code to see if I can achieve it, yet no success.

Comment: yeah, you only had to change those 2... as if it will return lots of records just to show you whats the real relation between account->friends and author->friends you need to `GROUP BY id` it in order to narrow those results down.